# Magento 2 mview_state mode disabled?

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexer

When I check indexer status with `php bin/magento indexer:status`, I got following result,

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Title                                | Status | Update On | Schedule Status | Schedule Updated |
+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Aheadworks One Step Checkout Reports | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Catalog Product Rule                 | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Catalog Rule Product                 | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Catalog Search                       | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Category Flat Data                   | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Category Products                    | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Customer Grid                        | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Design Config Grid                   | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product Categories                   | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product EAV                          | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product Flat Data                    | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product Price                        | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
| Stock                                | Ready  | Save      |                 |                  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Notice that I the column **Schedule status** and **Schedule updated** is empty, where it used to always have some information before. And When I check in the table `mview_state`, I can see the field **mode** is set to **disabled**, what does **disabled** mean?

I have never seen this before, and I never changed it to **disabled**, so how can it be **disabled** now.

Comment: OK, I found it out :). I just need to change the indexer mode to SCHEDULE. 
    php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule

Comment: That's correct. Read my answer here for some more context: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248556/magento-2-is-it-possible-to-run-reindexing-per-storeview/248580#248580